# Algoritmo para capitalizar a primeira letra de cada palavra

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer esse exercício para criação de algoritmo em JavaScript:

> "Crie um algorítimo para formatar nomes deixando as primeiras letras maiúsculas,exemplo rodrigo baptista de oliveira => Rodrigo Baptista De Oliveira"

Alguém por favor poderia me ajudar?

Não consigo fazer a ligação da função que formata as palavras com o `alert`.

```
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Clique aqui pequeno Padawan para inserir o nome.</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x;
    var idade = prompt("Digite o nome desejado Dudu");

  }

  String.prototype.capitalize = function(allWords) {
   return (allWords) ? // if all words
   this.split(' ').map(word => word.capitalize()).join(' ') :
   this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Uma boa prática para iniciarmos uma discussão saudável é fazer o [tour], caso ainda não tenha feito, e ler o guia de [ask]. Comece seguindo estas recomendações, principalmente sabendo quais os tipos de perguntas deve fazer, como criar um exemplo mínimo que seja completo e verificável e até mesmo o que fazer quando alguém te responder.

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Post seu código, mesmo que esteja cheio de erros.

Comment: Esta assim: https://jsfiddle.net/56un1w9v/1/  não consigo fazer a ligação da função que formata as palavras com o alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa função percorre as palavras de uma string, levando em consideração o espaço e troca o primeiro caracter por maíusculo:

```js
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}

var texto = 'rodrigo baptista de oliveira';
texto = capitalizeFirstLetter(texto);

console.log(texto)
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var Frase = "";
function myFunction() {
function primeiraLetraMaiuscula(Frase) {
   Frase  = prompt("Digite aqui");
   if (Frase != null) {
  var splitFrase = Frase.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < splitFrase.length; i++) {
        splitFrase[i] = splitFrase[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitFrase[i].substring(1);     
    }
   return splitFrase.join(' ');
   } 

}
var result = primeiraLetraMaiuscula();
//mostrará resultado no elemento de id = demo
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
//ou um alerta
//alert (result);
console.log(result)  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Clique aqui pequeno Padawan para inserir o nome.</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Obrigado Leo e Lucas,com as adaptações o código funcionou lindamente.Muito obrigado vocês me ajudaram bastante :).